# RestSharp.Portable read File from Stream

Tags: c#, rest, portable-class-library, restsharp

We use RestSarp.Portable in our project. This works perfeclty for most of our requests. 
But it doesn't work for a get requests, which sends a file via stream. I tested the request manual via browser. This is working.

It seems like RestSharp.Portable doesn't provide the method client.DownloadData(request) 
so know I have to read it manual from the response. 
My code is (at this moment, not working!)

```
var request = new RestRequest("someRequest", Method.GET);
var result = await client.Execute<HttpResponseMessage>(request);
var responseMessage = result.Data
var resultStream =  await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
```

result.Data seams to be null. Now what am I missing? Where is my fault

(Here my api method on the server:

```
 [Route("someRequest")]
 [HttpGet]
 public HttpResponseMessage getFile(){
 string path = getPath(req);
            try
            {
                MemoryStream responseStream = new MemoryStream();
                Stream fileStream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open);
                fileStream.CopyTo(responseStream);
                fileStream.Close();
                HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage
                {
                    StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
                    Content = new StreamContent(responseStream)
                };
                response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition =
                new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
                {
                    FileName = Path.GetFileName(path)
                };
                response.Content.Headers.ContentType =
                    new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
                return response;
            }
            catch (IOException)
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
            }
        }
```